# What does Spring MVC give you if you use JSTL on the view?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just starting to learn the Java side of things, sorry if this is obvious.  But, I was reading a tutorial about Spring in Java 6 and saw they were using just regular old JSTL on the view.

What does Spring give me if I am using JSTL for the view?  What would I use if I used "just java"  (I know it is all Java but I mean besides a framework like Spring or Struts)?

Thanks.

edit:

I guessed JSTL was the V.  That's my point.  If I already have the V without Spring, what do I get that I don't already have with Java?  What would I have to provide without Spring (please don't say MC!)

edit:  Maybe I'm asking.  What would I use in Java for MVC if I didn't use Spring, Struts or something like that.  What out of the box for MVC, with JSTL, do I have for Java 6.  What other components (I am keeping JSTL for a reason).  Thanks.

Comment: V as in You Vish there Vas a proper View layer available per default :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very simple example.
When in plain vanilla [Servlet model 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2) you write something like this:

```
public class AdditionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException {
        String x = request.getParameter("x");
        String y = request.getParameter("y");
        if (x == null || y == null) throw new ServletException();
        try {
            request.setAttribute("result", 
                Integer.parseInt(x) + Integer.parseInt(y));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/calc.jsp")
            .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

in Spring MVC you write this:

```
@Controller
public class ArithmeticController {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam("x") int x, @RequestParam("y") int y, 
        Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("result", x + y);
        return "calc";
    }
}
```

Both controllers use the same JSTL view, but amount of the boilerplate code differs.

Answer (score 0):

Main think that spring provided is [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control), imho.

Comment: There's a lot more to Spring than DI, including a huge web layer: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html

Comment: He was asking about Spring MVC specifically, not Spring in general.

Comment: @skaffman : Here quote: "What does Spring give me if I am using JSTL for the view?". So, I think, IoC will be useful)

Comment: @seanizer : Yep. But personally I think than Ioc/DI is some kind of basic/main idea in spring framework.

Comment: quote out of context.  The question specifically states "Spring MVC" and you can hardly miss that (well, at least **I** can hardly miss the title, but I don't doubt some people can).